# Programmatically Hide Soft Keyboard in ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageSelected()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

I have a ViewPager + ActionBar with tabs. I want to make the soft keyboard hide when I "swipe" to another tab but I can't figure out how.

I've passed in my Activity to the constructor for the FragmentPageAdapter so I can call

```
 activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

But it doesn't do anything (and it is in a reachable area of the code)...help?

Comment: /* To Hide Soft Keyboard */ 
In one Line:

`((InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your activity, you can do the following:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to use my viewPager as the view and do activity.getSystemService but the process worked

Comment: In One Line:

`((InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);`

Comment: you can set the view to the view pager so that you can use it without finding a view:   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mViewPager.getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: @AndroidGeek the viewpager itself can be passed for mView.

Answer (score 32):

I don't use `onPageSelected()` because the hide-keyboard animation screws with the swiping animation. Instead use `onPageScrollStateChanged()`:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
{
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
        {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(mViewPager.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better solution, no animation glitch. Tank you!

Answer (score 5):

Common way:

```
private void hideVirturalKeyboard(){
View v = getCurrentFocus();
if (v != null && v instanceof EditText) {
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)(v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVIC
E));
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)    
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case for fragment activity following is working fine.

```
((CommentActivity)getActivity()).pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int position) {
         final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtComment.getWindowToken(), 0);
     }

     @Override
     public void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
     }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
This was my fragment activity from which two fragments(CommentFragment,AnotherFragment) are opening in a ViewPager

```
public class CommentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        .......
        .......
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {
                case 0: return CommentFragment.newInstance();
                default: return AnotherFragment.newInstance();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }       
    }

}
```

If keypad is appear for an EditText in CommentFragment and want to switch to AnotherFragment and want to hide keypad at the time of switch

```
public class CommentFragment extends Fragment  {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .........
        .........
        .........
        ((CommentActivity)getActivity()).pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtComment.getWindowToken(), 0);
         }

         @Override
         public void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels) {
         }

         @Override
         public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
         }
   });
}
```