# Hide Soft Keyboard In Android App From ViewPager Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

I have an Android app that contains a ViewPager with 2 fragments.  The first fragment contains an EditText field.  When the app launches, that field immediately takes focus and the soft keyboard is launched (which I want to happen).  The second fragment only contains a list (no editable text fields).  When I swipe from fragment 1 to fragment 2, I'd like the keyboard to go away.  Nothing I've tried seems to work.  The keyboard not only remains in view, it continues to update fragment 1's EditText field.

I figure I'm either using incorrect code to hide the keyboard or placing it in an incorrect location.  If anyone can post an example of the correct implementation it would be greatly appreciated!

My latest attempt was to place code that should hide the keyboard in fragment 1's onDetach() method:

```
@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // I'VE TRIED ALL THREE BELOW, NONE OF THEM WORK...

        // imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.messageView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        // imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        // this.context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422905/769501) Basically, you need to have your ViewPager's `OnPageChangeListener` hide the keyboard for you. (If you want your swiping animation to remain smooth, do this in `onPageScrollStateChanged` instead of `onPageSelected`.)

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
{
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
        {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(mViewPager.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest you should add to Activity declaration android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden":

```
<activity 
        android:name="YourActivity"            
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">           
</activity>
```

And in your layout delete from EditText's children requestFocus:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the keyboard from displaying all the time?  I only want to hide it on fragment 2.

Comment: This prevents display the softkeyboard when the activity is loaded with your fragments. But if you click on some EditText, the softkeyboard will be displayed. Affects all fragments loaded by your Activity. For hide always and don't display never the softkeyboard, in the manifest you should use stateAlwaysHidden in android:windowSoftInputMode. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Almost works but when you switch back to a different fragment the keyboard isn't hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```